# Why I can't access to subdomain through nginx proxy pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I wanna to deploy my Ruby on Rails application in my local computer by `Nginx` and RoR web servers (like `Unicorn`, `Thin` or `WEBrick`).

As shown below, I wanna access to my web-app by `post` subdomain:

```
upstream sub {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.subdomain.sock fail_timeout=0;
#  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen   80;
  server_name post.subdomain.me;

  access_log /var/www/subdomain/log/access.log;
  error_log  /var/www/subdomain/log/error.log;
  root     /var/www/subdomain;
  index    index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @ruby;
  }

  location @ruby {
    proxy_pass http://sub;
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine and when I type `post.subdomain.me` I can see my RoR app.

**Problem:** When I use `post.subdomain.me` url I can't access to my subdomain (`request.subdomain` returns empty and `request.host` returns `subdomain` instaed of `subdomain.me`). But when I use `post.subdomain.me:3000` every things work perfect (I lost half of my hairs to realize that). Why and How can I resolve it?

Comment: What are you using for the HTTP server? You mentioned Unicorn, Thin and Webrick but didn't say which one you tried.

Comment: @TomL: With all of them I have same problem.

Comment: All of your `proxy_xxx` directives are in the wrong `location` block. You need to keep them with the `proxy_pass` directive in the `location @ruby` block, otherwise they will be ignored.

Comment: @RichardSmith: Could you please describe more about your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access app with port - you are accessing the rails server directly, not proxied by nginx, this is fine for debug, but usually is not well for production.

Probably host header is not passed over by client, `$host` defaults to nginx host

Try

```
location @ruby {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://sub;
}
```

And a 'hardcode'-way: `proxy_set_header Host post.subdomain.me;`

Comment: Edited to replace `$http_host` with `$host` or hardcode domain

Comment: Did you remove `proxy_set_header ` for host in `location /` section?

Comment: I'm really sorry, you were right. I was changing the wrong file.

Answer (score 2):

The `proxy_set_header` and `proxy_redirect` directives configure the `proxy_pass` directive and need to be within the same location block or inherited from the enclosing `server` block. You need to format your configuration file like this:

```
location / {
    try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @ruby;
}

location @ruby {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass http://sub;
}
```

EDIT: Assuming that `nginx` is not passing the information to RoR correctly, as @Vasfed suggested, try other values for `proxy_set_header Host`. There are three other candidates, all with slightly different meanings.

```
    proxy_set_header  Host post.subdomain.me;
    proxy_set_header  Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
```

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh EDIT: Explicitly stated Vasfed's suggestion.